# Obtener el porcentaje en SQL Server

Tags: sql

Tengo dos cantidades un valor total y un valor a la fecha y necesito sacar el porcentaje, ejemplo:

```
ValorTotal = 66215
ValorALaFecha = 5524
Porcentaje = ?
```

A que porcentaje equivale el *ValorALaFecha* del *ValorTotal*.

Comment: déjanos ver la estructura de la tabla o tablas que utiliza tu consulta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aplicando 3 simples  ((x * 100.0)/total)

```
Porcentaje = ((ValorALaFecha * 100.0)/ValorTotal )
```

Si son dos registro de la misma tabla

```
SELECT ValorTotal , ValorALaFecha , ((ValorALaFecha * 100.0)/ValorTotal )AS Porc from tabla
```